# Store business days according to week in Python (2.7)?

Tags: python, date, python-2.7, calendar

How can I create a Python script that will store business day dates coupled with their corresponding week number for any month?

That question is confusing, so here is a "visual":

```
August_2013 = {
  ( week1 : (8/1/2013),  (8/2/2013) ),
  ( week2 : (8/5/2013),  (8/6/2013),  (8/7/2013),  (8/8/2013),  (8/9/2013)  ),
  ( week3 : (8/12/2013), (8/13/2013), (8/14/2013), (8/15/2013), (8/16/2013) ),
  ( week4 : (8/19/2013), (8/20/2013), (8/21/2013), (8/22/2013), (8/23/2013) ),
  ( week5 : (8/26/2013), (8/27/2013), (8/28/2013), (8/29/2013), (8/30/2013) )
}
```

From searching all over SO, I wrote the following code for calculating the number of business days between two days:

```
def businessDays(start_date, end_date):
  day_generator = (start_date + timedelta(x + 1) for x in xrange((end_date - start_date).days))
  holidays = [ date(2013, 7, 4), date(2013, 12, 25) ] # Will add more later
  return sum(1 for day in day_generator if day.weekday() < 5 and day not in holidays)
```

But this code isn't enough.. I need to know how many business days were in which week of any given month.

Edit: My OS is Windows 7. I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: So, to simplify it, you have a list of holidays, and you want to create a mapping of how many business days were in every week for a particular month?

Comment: Exactly. Sorry, it's Friday and my mind is mush. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import calendar
import collections
from datetime import date

def get_weeks(year, month, holidays):
    cal = calendar.Calendar(0)
    weeks = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    for i, week in enumerate(cal.monthdatescalendar(year, month)):
        # Get just mon-fri
        for day in week[:-2]:
            if day.month == month and day not in holidays:
                weeks['week%s' % (i+1)] += 1
    return weeks
holidays = [date(2013, 8, 2), date(2013, 8, 6)]
print get_weeks(2013, 8, holidays)
```

This gives me:

```
{'week2': 4, 'week1': 1, 'week4': 5, 'week3': 5, 'week5': 5})
```

If I add another holiday on the 29th of August, I'll get:

```
>>> holidays = [date(2013, 8, 2), date(2013, 8, 6), date(2013, 8, 29)]
>>> print  get_weeks(2013, 8, holidays)
{'week2': 4, 'week1': 1, 'week4': 5, 'week3': 5, 'week5': 4})
```

*Update:*

```
import calendar
import collections
from datetime import date

def get_weeks(year, month, holidays):
    cal = calendar.Calendar(0)
    weeks = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for i, week in enumerate(cal.monthdatescalendar(year, month)):
        # Get just mon-fri
        for day in week[:-2]:
            if day.month == month and day not in holidays:
                weeks['week%s' % (i+1)].append(day)
    return weeks
holidays = [date(2013, 8, 2), date(2013, 8, 6), date(2013, 8, 29)]
print get_weeks(2013, 8, holidays)
```

This gives me:

```
{
  'week1': [date(2013, 8, 1)],
  'week2': [date(2013, 8, 5), date(2013, 8, 7), date(2013, 8, 8),
            date(2013, 8, 9)],
  'week3': [date(2013, 8, 12), date(2013, 8, 13), date(2013, 8, 14),
            date(2013, 8, 15), date(2013, 8, 16)],
  'week4': [date(2013, 8, 19), date(2013, 8, 20), date(2013, 8, 21),
            date(2013, 8, 22), date(2013, 8, 23)],
  'week5': [date(2013, 8, 26), date(2013, 8, 27), date(2013, 8, 28),
            date(2013, 8, 30)]
```

}

Comment: Gahh! I love you people and all of your knowledge. This works for calculation and storage is _almost_ perfect. Between this answer and Joowani's answer..I might be able to make it do exactly what I want.

Comment: Instead of storing the data as `{'week1' : 4}`, I need it stored like this: `{'week1' : (8/1/2013), (8/2/2013), etc}`.

Comment: I love you.. Seriously this helped.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly how you want to store the data, but is this sort of what you are looking for?

```
August_2013 = {}

def store(month, week, date):
    if week in month and date not in month[week]:
        month[week].append(date)
    else:
        month[week] = [date]

store(August_2013, "week1", "8/1/2013")
store(August_2013, "week1", "8/2/2013")
store(August_2013, "week2", "8/5/2013")

#calling August_2013 then returns {'week1': ['8/1/2013', '8/2/2013'], 'week2': ['8/5/2013']}
```

And to access your data you could do something like this:

```
def access(month, week):
    return month[week]

access(August_2013, "week1") # will return ['8/1/2013', '8/2/2013']
```

Comment: Thanks @Joowani. This is definitely moving me in the right direction, but it's not complete. I need a function for **calculating** and storing the days and weeks in any month. Your code helps me for the storage process, but not the calculating. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your "week of month" ends on a Sunday, and working days are Monday through Friday (based on your example)

```
import calendar
from datetime import date

def get_working_days(year, month, holidays):
  first_day, last_day = calendar.monthrange(year, month) # this gives the weekday of the first day of the month followed by the last day

  week = 1
  if first_day > 4: week = 0 # Assuming if you have Saturday, Sunday at the beginning of the month this doesn't start as the first week.

  working_days = {}

  for day in range(1, last_day+1):
    weekstr = 'week{0}'.format(week)
    if week > 0 and not weekstr in working_days:
      working_days[weekstr] = []
    today = date(year,month,day)
    if today.weekday() < 5:
      if today not in holidays:
        working_days[weekstr].append(today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
    if today.weekday() == 6:
      week += 1

  return working_days

holidays = [date(2013, 8, 2), date(2013, 8, 6)]
print get_working_days(2013, 8, holidays)
```

returns

```
{'week1': ['08/01/2013'], 'week3': ['08/12/2013', '08/13/2013', '08/14/2013', '08/15/2013', '08/16/2013'], 'week2': ['08/05/2013', '08/07/2013', '08/08/2013', '08/09/2013'], 'week5': ['08/26/2013', '08/27/2013', '08/28/2013', '08/29/2013', '08/30/2013'], 'week4': ['08/19/2013', '08/20/2013', '08/21/2013', '08/22/2013', '08/23/2013']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> def day_weekday(I_year, I_month):
    lst_weekday=[]
    lst_tmp=[]
    for day in range(1,32):
        try:
            day_temp=datetime.datetime(I_year, I_month, day)
            if day_temp.weekday() not in (6, 5):
                lst_tmp.append((I_year, I_month, day))
            elif len(lst_tmp)>0:
                lst_weekday.append(lst_tmp)
                lst_tmp=[]
            else:
                pass
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return lst_weekday, map(len, lst_weekday)

>>> day_weekday(2013, 8)
([[(2013, 8, 1), (2013, 8, 2)], \
 [(2013, 8, 5), (2013, 8, 6), (2013, 8, 7), (2013, 8, 8), (2013, 8, 9)], \
 [(2013, 8, 12), (2013, 8, 13), (2013, 8, 14), (2013, 8, 15), (2013, 8, 16)], \
 [(2013, 8, 19), (2013, 8, 20), (2013, 8, 21), (2013, 8, 22), (2013, 8, 23)], \
 [(2013, 8, 26), (2013, 8, 27), (2013, 8, 28), (2013, 8, 29), (2013, 8, 30)]], \
 [2, 5, 5, 5, 5])
```

The function returns two lists. The first one is a list of list and each list is the weekdays in that week. The second one is the number of weekdays of each week. You can format it into other format you want.